# Add Post number at Banning Page MyBB

Tags: post, numbers, mybb

There is a requirement to add total post count beside a banned member's profile name. See image below...
[image: Snapshot]

I tried with $post['postnum'] but it's not fetching any data.

Is there any code than can be used... please help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're attempting to get the user instance from `modcp.php` you can use `$ban['postnum']`.